# Vertical alignment of inline images

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, inline

Images appearing inline aren't always ideally placed relative to the baseline and risers of the text itself, so I frequently find myself doing manual adjustment, by eye, using `\raisebox{}{}` with a negative first parameter.

My question is whether there is a simple way to get a comparable effect without adjusting the parameter manually against the output in each case.

Comment: What kind of inline images are you using in what kind of situations? Are you maybe use images for symbols?

Comment: Finishing typesetting a Manchu-English dictionary. The dictionary is in romanization, but in a few places it is useful to cite the original Manchu script. However, images of actual handwritten Manchu look better than the Manchu fonts (accessible though MonTex).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Images are added with a zero depth, i.e. they sit on the baseline. It depends very much on the situation (and personal taste) what the "ideal" placement of a particular image is. So no, there is no way to automatically get-it-just-right (TM).

Note that `\raisebox` allows the use of `\height`, `\depth`, `\width` and `\totalheight` (=height+depth) which represent the original dimension of the to be raised box. As said, `\depth` is zero and so `\totalheight` is identical to `\height` for images. So if you want all you images to be 10% below the baseline you can use `\raisebox{-.1\height}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}`.

If you want the images to be as deep as the normal text you can use `\dp\strutbox` as a reference. The `\strutbox` contains the depth and height of a [`\strut`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strut_%28typesetting%29). Both together are equal to `\baselineskip` so about 20% larger than the actual font size. Therefore you might want to use `-.8\dp\strutbox`. Alternatively you can use a font size relative length in `ex`. `1ex` is about the height of an `x`.

As always you might want to make a macro for this if you need this more often.

Comment: Ah, very nice -- the use of \height always makes me happy. Thank you!

Comment: Another comment: If you want top-aligned images in the `figure` environment, you can use `\begin{figure}\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{img1.png}}\qquad\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{img2.png}}\end{figure}`

Comment: @tohecz: In the meantime since my answer I published `adjustbox` which can export the `valign` key to `\includegraphics`. It allows for easy vertical alignment and uses the the same internal macros as `\raisebox`.