# Inline TikZ - vertical centering

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, inline

If I inline a bounded line segment like this:

```
the distance \tikz{ \draw [|-|] (0,0) -- (5ex,0); } overarching the activities
```

how can I make the line appear vertically centered on the line (automatically taking into account the line height).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can directly tell where the baseline should meet the picture using the `baseline` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
the distance \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{ \draw [|-|] (0,0) -- (5ex,0); } overarching the activities
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To get a better vertical alignment see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59658/use-of-tikzpicture-matrix-in-align-or-gather-environment/59660#comment126261_59660).

Comment: **ex**: "roughly the height of an 'x' in the current font", see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths

Answer (score 3):

Neither percusse's nor Claudio's answer worked for me when I wanted to insert a small inline graph. Instead [Martin's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15858/69578) of `\raisebox` did work.

### Example

[image: Example]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %for drawing of graphs
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\begin{document}
The original one 
\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=10 ex, height = 3 ex, 
                 scale only axis, hide axis]
        \addplot[black] {rand};
    \end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}}
is too high.

And percusse's \verb|[baseline=-0.5 ex]|
\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
    \begin{axis}[width=10 ex, height = 3 ex, 
                 scale only axis, hide axis]
        \addplot[black] {rand};
    \end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}}
does not work, it only shifts 
\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=10 ex, height = 3 ex, 
                 scale only axis, hide axis]
        \addplot[black] {rand};
    \end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}}
the graph upwards a little.

\verb|\raisebox{-.5 ex}|
\raisebox{-.5 ex}{\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=10 ex, height = 3 ex, scale only axis,
    hide axis,
    ]
    \addplot[black] {rand};
    \end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
does work in this case, but I don't know why.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you are trying to push down -0.5ex adjust the baseline position for that example. As I commented, you can adjust with `baseline` to be **wherever** you want.

Comment: @percusse Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. You mean you can also push them in a positive direction? I've tried that, but that does nothing.

Comment: Question: is `3 ex` the height that won't mess with the interline? Also, to answer your question, you wanted to push the baseline `1 ex` **down** (positive value, not negative), not just `0.5 ex` (you got the amount and sign wrong in your reply) since the total height is `3 ex` and you want it centred at mid `x`'s height, which is `0.5 ex`.