# How to make a simple line with two sided arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[aps,amsmath,article,amsfonts,11pt]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphics,bm}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
 \usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{twotriang}{twotriang}%
{triangle 90}{triangle 90}{triangle 90}{triangle 90}
%\setlength\topmargin{0.0005 in}


\begin{document}
  C1  \xleftrightarrow{\text{\hspace*{1cm}   }} C2
```

I am using this code but nothing happening.
I want to make a two sided arrow between two function like this:-                   C1 <----------------> C2                                                            I am using here dash line. but i need solid line here.                                  If anyone can figure it out, most welcome.

Comment: Maybe help : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57020/31034

Comment: well its helpful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `TiKZ` for that. `\xleftrightarrow` is not defined by default. Here is how to do it. It has to be used in math mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, old-arrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xleftrightarrow[2][]{%
 \ext@arrow 9999{\longleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\longleftrightarrowfill@{%
 \arrowfill@ \leftarrow \relbar \rightarrow }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

C1 $\xleftrightarrow{\hspace*{1cm}}$ C2

\end{document}
```

[image]