Minipage inside fbox is not aligning to top
I have two minipages inside a box as seen in the picture below. I want both sides to format to the top, but the right hand side is not formatting even if I use [t].

The code is:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\definecolor{b1}{rgb}{0,0.2784313725490196,0.6705882352941176}
\definecolor{r1}{rgb}{0.8901960784313725,0.14901960784313725,0.21176470588235294}
\definecolor{grey1}{rgb}{0.8274509803921568,0.8274509803921568,0.8274509803921568}
\definecolor{g1}{rgb}{0.4666666666666667,0.8666666666666667,0.4666666666666667}
\title{Math Notes}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{black}{g1!5!white}{
        \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{
            \begin{center}
                \underline{Example: Graph $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ if $f(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)(x-1)(x+3)$}
            \end{center}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item[1)]
                    \resizebox{150pt}{!}{
                        \begin{tikzpicture}
                            \begin{axis}[
                                xmin=-5,
                                xmax=5,
                                ymin=-5,
                                ymax=5,
                                xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                xticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                yticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                xticklabel style={anchor=north},
                                axis lines=middle,
                                axis line style={line width=1pt},
                                xlabel={$x$},
                                ylabel={$f(x)$},
                                xlabel style={anchor=south west},
                                ylabel style={anchor=south west}
                            ]
                                \addplot[
                                    color=r1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-4:1
                                ]{x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3)};  
                                \addplot[
                                    color=r1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=1:3
                                ]{x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3)};  
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}
                    }
                    \item[2)]
                    \resizebox{150pt}{!}{
                        \begin{tikzpicture}
                            \begin{axis}[
                                xmin=-5,
                                xmax=5,
                                ymin=-5,
                                ymax=5,
                                xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                xticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                yticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                xticklabel style={anchor=north},
                                axis lines=middle,
                                axis line style={line width=1pt},
                                xlabel={$x$},
                                ylabel={$f(x)$},
                                xlabel style={anchor=south west},
                                ylabel style={anchor=south west}
                            ]
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-6:-3.001
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-2.999:-2.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-1.999:-1.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-0.999:-0.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    color=b1,
                                    domain=0.01:0.999
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=250,
                                    domain=1.001:6
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-3,-5) (-3,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-2,-5) (-2,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-1,-5) (-1,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(0,-5) (0,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed,
                                ]coordinates{(1,-5) (1,5)};
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}
                    }
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{minipage}%
            \vline
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item[1)]$f(x)$ is drawn.
                    \item[2)]Roots at $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1$, $\therefore$ vertical asymptotes at $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1$. 
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{minipage}
            }
}
\end{center}
\end{document}

And also if the example text is to wide it doesn't wrap around to the next line, how do I fix that? 

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Your code does not compile

Sorry I forgot to add the colour definitions

Please don't include multiple questions in one post. As for the missing line wrap: \underline does not break lines. Have a look at the soul package or - better - lua-ul if you can compile with lualatex.

Thanks, the soul package fixed the underline issue but idk how to fix the minipages

The minipages are both top aligned as you can see, the 1) in both are at the same vertical place. You problem is, that the tikzpictures more or less have not depth but only height. So the baseline is at the bottom of the tikzpicture.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57019/277964

@cabohah I changed each minipage begin to \begin{minipage}[baseline=0ex]{0.5\textwidth}. This fixed one of my boxes, but the original still looks the same

minipage does not support an option baseline=0ex. baseline would be an option to tikzpicture, but using the value 0ex would not help. See the two linked questions and the TikZ manual for more information. Note, that there are also alternatives at least in the second answer of the link in my second comment.

The first answer didn't work. How do I use baseline when there is no tikzpicture in the second minipage?

Zarko has demonstrated exactly this in his answer to the question I've linked in my first comment.

The optional t alignment for minipage does not mean align with the top edge of the minipage but align the top baseline of the minipage with the current baseline
As you can see from the vertical alignment of the list item “1)” from the two minipage environments, this is already the case in your example.
However, as you can see from the vertical alignment of the list item “1)” with the tikzpicture environment, almost the entire image is above the baseline.
One possible option would therefore be to move the baseline of the tikzpicture to its upper end. As already shown in the answers to several other questions, e.g., Zarko's answer to “Adjusting tikzpicture baseline to be flush”, you can change the baseline of a tikzpicture using the baseline option:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\definecolor{b1}{rgb}{0,0.2784313725490196,0.6705882352941176}
\definecolor{r1}{rgb}{0.8901960784313725,0.14901960784313725,0.21176470588235294}
\definecolor{grey1}{rgb}{0.8274509803921568,0.8274509803921568,0.8274509803921568}
\definecolor{g1}{rgb}{0.4666666666666667,0.8666666666666667,0.4666666666666667}
\title{Math Notes}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{black}{g1!5!white}{
        \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{
            \begin{center}
                \underline{Example: Graph $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ if $f(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)(x-1)(x+3)$}
            \end{center}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item[1)]
                    \resizebox{150pt}{!}{%
                        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding
                          box.north west)]
                            \begin{axis}[
                                xmin=-5,
                                xmax=5,
                                ymin=-5,
                                ymax=5,
                                xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                xticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                yticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                xticklabel style={anchor=north},
                                axis lines=middle,
                                axis line style={line width=1pt},
                                xlabel={$x$},
                                ylabel={$f(x)$},
                                xlabel style={anchor=south west},
                                ylabel style={anchor=south west}
                            ]
                                \addplot[
                                    color=r1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-4:1
                                ]{x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3)};  
                                \addplot[
                                    color=r1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=1:3
                                ]{x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3)};  
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}%
                    }
                    \item[2)]
                    \resizebox{150pt}{!}{%
                        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding
                          box.north west)]
                            \begin{axis}[
                                xmin=-5,
                                xmax=5,
                                ymin=-5,
                                ymax=5,
                                xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                xticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                yticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                xticklabel style={anchor=north},
                                axis lines=middle,
                                axis line style={line width=1pt},
                                xlabel={$x$},
                                ylabel={$f(x)$},
                                xlabel style={anchor=south west},
                                ylabel style={anchor=south west}
                            ]
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-6:-3.001
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-2.999:-2.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-1.999:-1.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-0.999:-0.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    color=b1,
                                    domain=0.01:0.999
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=250,
                                    domain=1.001:6
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-3,-5) (-3,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-2,-5) (-2,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-1,-5) (-1,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(0,-5) (0,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed,
                                ]coordinates{(1,-5) (1,5)};
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}%
                    }
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{minipage}%
            \vline
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item[1)]$f(x)$ is drawn.
                    \item[2)]Roots at $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1$, $\therefore$ vertical asymptotes at $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1$. 
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{minipage}
            }
}
\end{center}
\end{document}


But if you want the “1)” and “2)” still at the bottom of the plots, also Sriotchilism O'Zaic's suggestion would work:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\definecolor{b1}{rgb}{0,0.2784313725490196,0.6705882352941176}
\definecolor{r1}{rgb}{0.8901960784313725,0.14901960784313725,0.21176470588235294}
\definecolor{grey1}{rgb}{0.8274509803921568,0.8274509803921568,0.8274509803921568}
\definecolor{g1}{rgb}{0.4666666666666667,0.8666666666666667,0.4666666666666667}
\title{Math Notes}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{black}{g1!5!white}{
        \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{
            \begin{center}
                \underline{Example: Graph $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ if $f(x)=x(x+1)(x+2)(x-1)(x+3)$}
            \end{center}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
              \vspace{0mm}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item[1)]
                    \resizebox{150pt}{!}{%
                        \begin{tikzpicture}
                            \begin{axis}[
                                xmin=-5,
                                xmax=5,
                                ymin=-5,
                                ymax=5,
                                xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                xticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                yticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                xticklabel style={anchor=north},
                                axis lines=middle,
                                axis line style={line width=1pt},
                                xlabel={$x$},
                                ylabel={$f(x)$},
                                xlabel style={anchor=south west},
                                ylabel style={anchor=south west}
                            ]
                                \addplot[
                                    color=r1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-4:1
                                ]{x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3)};  
                                \addplot[
                                    color=r1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=1:3
                                ]{x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3)};  
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}%
                    }
                    \item[2)]
                    \resizebox{150pt}{!}{%
                        \begin{tikzpicture}
                            \begin{axis}[
                                xmin=-5,
                                xmax=5,
                                ymin=-5,
                                ymax=5,
                                xtick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
                                xticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                yticklabels={,-4,,,,,,,,4,},
                                xticklabel style={anchor=north},
                                axis lines=middle,
                                axis line style={line width=1pt},
                                xlabel={$x$},
                                ylabel={$f(x)$},
                                xlabel style={anchor=south west},
                                ylabel style={anchor=south west}
                            ]
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-6:-3.001
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-2.999:-2.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-1.999:-1.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=100,
                                    domain=-0.999:-0.01
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    color=b1,
                                    domain=0.01:0.999
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    color=b1,
                                    samples=250,
                                    domain=1.001:6
                                ]{(1)/(x*(x+1)*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x+3))}; 
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-3,-5) (-3,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-2,-5) (-2,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(-1,-5) (-1,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed
                                ]coordinates{(0,-5) (0,5)};
                                \addplot[
                                    samples=100,
                                    dashed,
                                ]coordinates{(1,-5) (1,5)};
                            \end{axis}
                        \end{tikzpicture}%
                    }
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{minipage}%
            \vline
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item[1)]$f(x)$ is drawn.
                    \item[2)]Roots at $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1$, $\therefore$ vertical asymptotes at $x=-3,-2,-1,0,1$. 
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{minipage}
            }
}
\end{center}
\end{document}


So because all answers to that question would solve your problem, your question is IMHO a duplicate of Adjusting tikzpicture baseline to be flush.
