# vertical placement of graphics in marginpar

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, marginpar

I'd like to put small graphics into the margin via `\marginpar`. The top of the figures shall be aligned to the top of the text line they refer to. I found around here the suggestion to put a `\vskip0pt` into the `marginpar`, which seems to work somewhat, but the placement is still not perfect. In good LaTeX style I would like to have a solution that works automatically, i.e., without pixel-adjusting manually every figure, and is robust (font sizes, line spreads etc.).

In the following MWE the problem is particularly visible in 1.2.1 and 1.2.2

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{Graphical note}
\subsection{With new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.

% \leavevmode% makes things worse
%% \vksip3pt seems to be correct
\marginpar{\vskip0pt\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}%

% \leavevmode% makes things worse
%% seems OK
\marginpar{\vskip0pt\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsection{Without new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
%% \vksip-7pt seems to be correct
\marginpar{\vskip0pt\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}%
%% \vksip-7pt seems to be correct
\marginpar{\vskip0pt\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\clearpage
\section{With textual note}
The following four cases work fine.
\subsection{With new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.

\leavevmode%
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}

\leavevmode%
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsection{Without new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `.7` multiplier of `\baselineskip` for fine-tuned adjustments.  Note, the `\rule` at the beginning of `\ffig` is an artificial way to ensure that a new paragraph is started.  If `\marginpar` is otherwise called at the very beginning of a paragraph, it actually attaches itself to the last line of the prior paragraph.  Since you had several instances of wanting to place your `\marginpar` at the beginning of a paragraph, this was needed.  Also, the `\height` parameter adjustment was mentioned by Martin Scharrer, at [Vertical alignment of inline images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15853/vertical-alignment-of-inline-images/15858#15858).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand\ffig[1]{%
  \rule{0ex}{1ex}%
  \marginpar{\smash{\raisebox{.7\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Graphical note}
\subsection{With new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.

\ffig{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}%

\ffig{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsection{Without new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\ffig{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}%
\ffig{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{test}}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\clearpage
\section{With textual note}
The following four cases work fine.
\subsection{With new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.

\leavevmode%
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}

\leavevmode%
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsection{Without new paragraph}
\subsubsection{Text blocks}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\subsubsection{Equation ending}

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}
\marginpar{Baz baz baz baz baz}%
Bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to collapse the two `raisebox`es into one (using the `calc` package for computation). The code is also not robust regarding font sizes: making the text `\Huge` requires adaption of the `0.7\baselineskip`. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @mafp Both valid points. I always debate internally on whether to load another package (in this case calc) or make a less efficient command (nested `\raisebox`).

Comment: I'm fine with that. Btw, I changed the `\raisebox` parameter to `\ht\strutbox-\height`, this seems to be conceptually clearer.

Comment: I just found out that `\marginnote` of the `marginnote` package works out of the box, except for text size changes. So I think I will use that.