# How you can put an image in a footnote on page?

Tags: graphics, floats, footnotes

How you can put an image in a footnote on page?

try this, but does not work

```
\footnote {bla bla
\begin {figure}
....
\end{figure}
}
```

Comment: You don't have to (and here should not) use `figure`, use `\includegraphics` directly.

Comment: muchas gracias

era muy facil =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The Solution**

Simply use `\includegraphics` command from the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) 
package to include your image. This is nothing different from putting an image at any other location, including inside a `figure` environment.

You use the `figure` environment *only* when your image is a float (which is true is most of the cases, though). In a footnote, as desired by you, it is not.

There will be no harm even if you do not include an actual image inside `figure`. You may want to put some text as your *figure* and LaTeX will not complain.

---

**MWE Code**

Anyway, here is a minimal solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text only

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{This footnote contains an image as well.
  \includegraphics[height=5.0mm]{logo.png}}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

---

**Further Tweaking**

With a little tweaking, you can take care of vertical alignment of the image. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15853/vertical-alignment-of-inline-images) should you need any help.

---

**Output**

[image]

Comment: tnx =) it was very easy jiji