# How can I align the image with other minipages?

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, includegraphics

I'm using a template to write my resume (unfortunately I cannot find the source anymore, but I think it's a variation of [liantze/AltaCV](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV)), and I wanted to extend it with a section formatted for projects, using **minipages**.

I'd like to get **3 columns**:

- **left one**, containing the *project title* and some other info (date, course etc.);
- **center one**, containing the *project description*;
- **right one**, containing an *image*.

However, for some reason I can't figure out, the image is getting displayed above the other minipages.

## What I'm getting

[image]

## Desired result

[image]

## Code

### Class file (.cls)

I added the following:

```latex
\newcommand{\mygraphic}[1]{
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{#1}}

\newlength{\projectExtendedLeft}
\newlength{\projectExtendedCenter}
\newlength{\projectExtendedRight}
\setlength{\projectExtendedLeft}{0.2\textwidth}
\setlength{\projectExtendedCenter}{0.49\textwidth}
\setlength{\projectExtendedRight}{0.3\textwidth}
\newcommand{\projectExtended}[5]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\projectExtendedLeft}% minipage for left column with name/date/course
        % PROJECT TITLE ---------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\projectExtendedLeft}
            {\Large \color{emphasis} #1}
        \end{minipage}
        \vspace{0.5em}
        \par
        % PROJECT DATE ----------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3mm}% wrap marker in minipage to allow multi-line dates
            \makebox[3mm][c]{\faCalendar}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace{0.5 em}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \projectExtendedLeft-3mm-0.5em}% wrap date in minipage to allow multi-line dates
            #2
        \end{minipage}%
        \par
        \vspace{0.1em}
        % PROJECT COURSE --------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3mm}% wrap marker in minipage to allow multi-line courses
            \makebox[3mm][c]{\faBook}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace{0.5em}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \projectExtendedLeft-3mm-0.5em}% wrap place in minipage to allow multi-line courses
            #3
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    % PROJECT DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\projectExtendedCenter}% minipage for description
        #4
        \par \normalsize
        \vspace{0.5em}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    % PROJECT IMAGE -------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\projectExtendedRight}% minipage for picture
        \centering
        \mygraphic{#5}
        \label{fig:prova}
    \end{minipage}%
}
```

### Main (.tex)

```latex
\section{Other Projects}
    \projectExtended{\href{https://github.com/mikyll}{\textbf{Project Name}}}
        {From - To}
        {\href{https://www.unibo.it/}{Course Name}}
        {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.}
        {gfx/walle-placeholder.jpg}
```

---

I'm not much experienced in LaTeX, so let me know if you need further details to investigate the problem.

Comment: The baseline of a `\includegraphics` is at the bottom of the image. Alignment `t` for `minipage` or `\parbox` does mean: align the baseline of the top element with the baseline outside the box. So you need to move the baseline of the `\includegraphics` upwards. You can do this either using `\raisebox` or using [package `adjustbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34166/277964

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15853/277964

Comment: @cabohah thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

As suggested by [cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277964/cabohah) (thank you so much ), the problem was that with minipage `[t]` option the **baseline** of the top element gets aligned with the baseline outside the box, and `\includegraphics` baseline is at the bottom of the image.

## Solution

In order to align the image with other minipages, I needed to move its baseline upwards (for example using `\raisebox` command). Therefore, I obtained the desired result by wrapping `\includegraphics` in a `\raisebox{-\height}` command which raised the picture by its height:

```latex
\newcommand{\mygraphic}[1]{
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{#1}}}
```

## Result

[image]